# How to limit rows in MySQL when using UNION ALL

Tags: mysql, where-clause, union-all

I have the following query

```
$query_string = '
          (SELECT advisorBITname AS bitName, advisorName AS fullName, includeInCache AS cacheInclude
          FROM advisors AS advisor
          WHERE advisor.cacheInclude = "1")
          UNION ALL
          (SELECT user_id AS bitName, user_name AS fullName, includeInCache AS cacheInclude
          FROM users AS user
          WHERE user.user_role != "S" AND user.user_status = "A" AND user.cacheInclude = "1")
          ORDER BY fullName
        ';
```

No matter what I try -- using the parens; eliminating the parens, putting the WHERE arguments on the user section or including the WHERE ojn each table -- the query fails always with `Unknown column 'advisor.cacheInclude' in 'where clause'`

Note there is an `includeInCache` column on the advisors table and an `includeInCache` column on the users table

Comment: try `advisor.includeInCache = '1'`

Comment: ok, thanks @PathikVejani. I changed both WHERE's to `*.includeInCache` and it finally worked. I truly believe that I tried that many times over but I guess I did not because I got it to work now. Thanks a million!!